# D3.js Overlaying Barchart display error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im trying to produce a similar image as the following: [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdtuA.png)

but by barcharts are getting overlayed and I cant add the axes correctly.

My code is the follwing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var birth_years = [];
var count_birth = [];
for(i = 0; i<json_final.length; i++) {
    birth_years.push(json_final[i].birth_year);
    count_birth.push(json_final[i].count);
}
var ages = [] //age is the data
for (var i = 0; i < birth_years.length; i++) {
    //count_birth is the number of people whose birth date is indicated by birth_year
    ages.push({"age": new Date().getFullYear() - birth_years[i], "number_of_people": count_birth[i]});
}

console.log(ages);

var results,
    chart,
    bars,
    margin = 100,
    w = 8,
    h = 500,
    x, y,
    xAxis, yAxis;

results = d3.map(ages);


chart = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('class', 'chart')
        .attr('width', 100)
        .attr('height', h)
        .append('g')


d3.select('svg g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(50, 50)');

x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([10,80])
    .rangeRound(0, 550),

 y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain( [0, d3.max( ages, function( d ) { return d.number_of_people; } )] )
    .rangeRound( [0, h - margin] );



// Bars
bars = chart.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'bars');
 bars.selectAll( 'rect' )
    .data( ages )
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', function( d, i ) { return d.age  } )
    .attr( 'y', function( d ) { return (h - margin) - y( d.number_of_people )} )
    .attr( 'width', w )
    .attr( 'height', function( d ) { return y( d.number_of_people ) } )
    .append('g');
//console.log(t);



// Axis - I get some errors when I tried to use this
xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(20)
    .orient('bottom')
    .tickSize(6, 3, 1);

yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(d3.scale.linear().domain( [0, d3.max( ages, function( d ) { return d.number_of_people; } )] ).rangeRound( [h - margin, 0] ))
    .tickSize(6, 3, 1)
    .orient('left');
```

The image that I'm getting so far is basically this one:

[My graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwCmv.png)

If someone helps me it would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in short: 
I think its a number of problems here. First, your svg container seems to be only 100 units wide:

```
chart = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('class', 'chart')
        .attr('width', 100)
        .attr('height', h)
        .append('g')
```

The rect you want to append all have to same size, being var 'w' which is 8 units:

```
var results,
    chart,
    bars,
    margin = 100,
    w = 8,
    h = 500,
    x, y,
    xAxis, yAxis;
...
bars = chart.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'bars');
 bars.selectAll( 'rect' )
    .data( ages )
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        ...
    .attr( 'width', w )
      ...
    .append('g');
```

And finally, when appending the 'rect' elements, you position the 'x' attribute equal to the age. This means that if you have ages to display, lets say, 50 people with age 20, and 30 people with age 21 and 45 people with age 22. The rect elements will be placed on the X axes on position 20, 21 and 22, causing them to be only 1 unit away from each other, since the ages differ only by one. BUT... the bars have a fixed with of 8 units (which I already said), so they overlap on ages that are close to each other.

So in order to fix this, I would make my svg element wider and use a function to position your bars on the x axe. I would use an ordinal scale for the ages:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(agesArray).rangeRoundBands([0,chartwidth - margins], .1);
```

Something like this. The last '.1' for the rangeBands stands for a small space between the bars when rendered.

For an excellent example of creating a barchart, check this book out: [Interactive Data Visualization for the Web, by Scott Murray](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch06.html#_making_a_bar_chart)

I learned a lot from it. If you still have more questions, feel free to ask!